# Accessing MySQL database - D3

Tags: php, mysql, d3.js

I have a basic line graph and attempting to access a mySQL database. I'm going wrong somewhere with the PHP and/or how handling the JSON returned -  can anyone help shed some light?
At the moment the graph is not displaying at all and getting error message "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token >" for the html tag -  no idea why as syntax is correct as far as I can see?

http://bl.ocks.org/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

"getdata.php" as follows:

```
    <?php

    $username="******"; 
    $password="******";   
    $host="********";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    @mysql_select_db($link) or die( "Unable to select database");

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT reading, COUNT(TYPE) AS 'type' FROM    TestSourceSampleData ");
    $rows = array();

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[$r['reading']] = $r['type'];}

    echo json_encode($rows);
    mysql_close();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the `svg` tag in the static part; I think the `xmlns` is missing. You could make the `svg:` namespace at the top.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" height="290">
```

Also check by typing in getdata.php in your browser (to look whether the data is correctly delivered).

Comment: xlmns not missing, I'm using HTML5. Getting "unable to select database" when go directly to getdata.php.

Comment: That "unable" error: could have been a relative include path problem, but here unlikely (?). In JavaScript the same simple URL is called, so that is something to resolve.

Comment: Meant to add below as comment - NOT to answer my own question. As said below PHP is now correct, although getting "Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected token" now with "}" instead of ">". I'm taking it as PHP correct and HTML5 syntax correct as far as I can see - the problem has to be with the visualisation code - http://bl.ocks.org/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23?

Comment: Tweaked PHP code and this error been replaced with a parse error.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have done the trick - while statement was worded and formatted incorrectly:

getdata.php is now as follows:

```
    <?php
    $username="***"; 
    $password="****";   
    $host="*****";

    $link=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    mysql_select_db("****", $link) or die( "Unable to select database" );

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT reading FROM TestSourceSampleData", $link)
      or die ("Unable to run query");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {       
    $reading = $row["reading"];
    echo json_encode($row);
    }    
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```