# JSON Parse Error in D3,js

Tags: php, json, d3.js

Following on from this thread: [Accessing MySQL database - D3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13783204/accessing-mysql-database-d3)

Can anyone help with a parse error I'm getting?  There seems to be conflicting information out there about what can cause this?

**Parse error:**

Error: Problem parsing d="M30,NaNL34,NaNL38,NaNL42,NaNL46,NaNL50,NaNL54,NaNL58.......

**getdata.php:**

```
    <?php
    $username="*****"; 
    $password="*****";   
    $host="********";
    $link=mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

    mysql_select_db("*****", $link) or die( "Unable to select database"
    .mysql_error());

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TestSourceSampleData")
    or die ("Unable to run query");
    $data = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {  
    $data[] = array("reading" => $row['reading']);
    } 
    echo json_encode($data);     
    mysql_close($link);
    ?>
```

**Output from getdata.php:**

[{"reading":"10"},{"reading":"10.2"},{"reading":"10.3"},{"reading":"10.3"}........

**..when print json file:**

```
    Array[120]
    [0 … 99]
    0: Object
    reading: "10"
    __proto__: Object
    1: Object
    reading: "10.2"
    __proto__: Object
    2: Object
    reading: "10.3"
    __proto__: Object
    3: Object
    4: Object
    5: Object
```

http://bl.ocks.org/5fc4cd5f41a6ddf2df23

Comment: it's not clear where the parsing code is - if this is where the error is, best to post the code where the JSON is fed in and parsed.    The "printing json file" bit look like a copy-paste from a javascript console - if you're looking to dump that info, you might try `JSON.stringify()` to get clearer output.

Comment: Thanks - was a copy-paste! I'll use the stringify method from now on.  The link to the code is at the bottom of the post above . First encounter with this so unsure how to go about parsing the JSON?

Comment: oops, I didn't catch the parsing code in the external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your block you use:

```
var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.Value; });
```

while in your question you mention that the name of the key is `reading`, which would mean your code should look like:

```
var data = jsondata.map(function(d) { return d.reading; });
```

Comment: Thank you - should have realised that myself.  Working perfectly now:)